# Clearing values from react-select

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I have created this function inside onChange to handle my inputs using react-select. it works perfectly fine in terms of submitting the input and using it later. The thing is, the clear property is not working. Before I created my function inside onChange, it used to work whenever I click on "x". Yet now it is not. Any help?

```
  {["role1", "role2", "role3"].map(role => (
          <Select
            cacheOptions
            defaultOptions
            loadOptions={this.loadOptions}
            key={role}
            getOptionLabel={i => i.full_name}
            getOptionValue={i => i.id}
            closeMenuOnSelect={false}
            isMulti
            className="selectStyle"
            placeholder={t(role)}
            value={form.users.filter(item => item.role === role)}
            onChange={values => {
              let newValues = form.users;

              values.forEach(item => {
                if (
                  newValues.filter(v => v.id === item.id && v.role === role)
                    .length
                ) {
                  return;
                }

                item.role = role;
                newValues.push(item);
              });

              setFormValue({ name: "users", value: newValues });
            }}
            clearValue={() => {
              setFormValue({
                name: "users",
                value: form.users.filter(item => item.role !== role)
              });
            }}
          />
```

Comment: what's the output of your current clearValue ?

Comment: This is a function to handle the selection process. I have created it to be able to use the same option in multiple inputs.